# Check how much the screen position has changed appium android

Tags: android, testing, appium

I am running the Android test with appium, and during the execution of test I perform swipe on a screen, how can I find out how many pixels I moved in relation to original position?

Comment: Please mark an answer here or update accordingly please

Answer (score 2):

you can get it via **UIAutomator viewe**r. Launch it and select an element . look for the coordinates/pixel in the right corner of the automator viewer, keep hovering right to left(vice versa) on the element. you can see the coordinates being changed
[image]

Answer (score 1):

***Assumption*** : Let `sureElement` be an element which would remain in the view (on screen) after you have performed the swipe.

the way you can find out the pixels moved relatively now is evaluating the difference in its coordinates :

**Case 1 : Horizontal Swipe**

```
int initialX = sureElement.getLocation().getX();
...perform swipe
int finalX = sureElement.getLocation().getX();
int yourDesiredPixels = finalX-initialX;
```

**Case 2 : Vertical Swipe**

```
int initialY = sureElement.getLocation().getY();
...perform swipe
int finalY = sureElement.getLocation().getY();
int yourDesiredPixels = finalY-initialY; //possibly this is what you are seeking
```

Deep thoughts about location and x,y coordinates can be digged further from here : 
https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getLocation--